# Searching within Nested lists in Python || How do I match a 1-index nested list, with a 2-index nested list

Tags: python, nested-loops

here is the problem I am trying to solve:

```
coord = [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2] ..]

new_arr = [[[0, 0], 1], [[1, 0], 1], [[1, 1], 1], [[2, 0], 1], [[2, 1], 2], [[2, 2], 1] ..]
```

[This is the target I am trying to map to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV84B.png)

```
[0, 0][0, 1][0, 2]
[1, 0][1, 1][1, 2]
[2, 0][2, 1][2, 2]
```

[the ultimate output would be the counts against each of the coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7bCd.png)

```
1 0 0 
1 1 0 
1 2 1
```

------ clarifications --------

the goal is to generate this square of numbers (counts) which is the second element in new_arr. E.g. [[0, 0], 1], [[1, 0], 1], can be interpreted as the value 1 for the coordinate [0,0] and value 1 for coordinate [1,0]

the first list (coord) is simply a map of the coordinates. The goal is to get the corresponding value (from new_arr) and display it in the form of a square. Hope this clarified. The output will be a grid of the format

```
1 0 0 
1 1 0 
1 2 1
```

to the question of N (I just took a sample value of 3). The actual use case is when the user enters an integer, say 6 and the result is in a 6 X 6 square. The counts are chess move computations on the ways to reach a specific cell (two movements only (i+1, j) & (i+1, j+1) ....... starting from (0,0)

Comment: Please be more specific on what your goal is. Like this it is hard to understand.

Comment: The logic is unclear, please break down an example

Comment: the goal is to generate this square of numbers (counts) which is the second element in new_arr. E.g. [[0, 0], 1], [[1, 0], 1], can be interpreted as the value 1 for the coordinate [0,0] and value 1 for coordinate [1,0]

Comment: the first list (coord) is simply a map of the coordinates. The goal is to get the corresponding value (from new_arr) and display it in the form of a square. Hope this clarified. The output will be a grid of the format

Comment: 1 0 0 /n
1 1 0 /n
1 2 1

Comment: to the question of N (I just took a sample value of 3). The actual use case is when the user enters an integer, say 6 and the result is in a 6 X 6 square. The counts are chess move computations on the ways to reach a specific cell (two movements  only (i+1, j) & (i+1, j+1) ....... starting from (0,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is not fully clear, but is looks like you want to map the values of `new_arr` on the Cartesian product of coordinates:

```
N = 3 # how this is determined is unclear

d = {tuple(l):x for l, x in new_arr}
# {(0, 0): 1, (1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 1, (2, 0): 1, (2, 1): 2, (2, 2): 1}

out = [d.get((i,j), 0) for i in range(N) for j in range(N)]
# [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1]

# 2D variant
out2 = [[d.get((i,j), 0) for j in range(N)] for i in range(N)]
# [[1, 0, 0],
#  [1, 1, 0],
#  [1, 2, 1]]
```

##### alternative with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)

```
import numpy as np

N = 3
a = np.zeros((N,N), dtype=int)

# get indices and values
idx, val = zip(*new_arr)

# assign values (option 1)
a[tuple(zip(*idx))] = val

# assign values (option 2)
a[tuple(np.array(idx).T.tolist())] = val

print(a)
```

output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 1]])
```

Comment: thank you for the comment. Here is some additional info.

Comment: @Ziba please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73726501/edit) the question if you have any additional info

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

i = []
coord = [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2]]

new_arr = [[[0, 0], 1], [[1, 0], 1], [[1, 1], 1], [[2, 0], 1], [[2, 1], 2], [[2, 2], 1]]

result = np.zeros([coord[-1][0] + 1, coord[-1][1] + 1])
 
for i in new_arr:
    for j in coord:
        if i[0] == j:
            result[j[0],j[1]]= i[1]
        
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 2. 1.]]
```

Comment: isn't is counterproductive to use numpy if you'll loop over the indices? (I added a vectorial solution) ;)

Comment: @mozway I just used a simple way ;)